# Connecting to AWS with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS RDS and I am trying to connect MySQL workbench to the instance on AWS. I want to have full admin access in the Database.

Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP over SSH
SSH Hostname: (AWS given endpoint)
SSH UserName: (not sure which user name they are asking for...ec2 or root?)
SHH Password: 
SSH Keyfile: assuming this is the .pem file from AWS
MySQL HostName: 127.0.0.1
MySQL ServerPort: 3306
username: mysql username 
password: mysql username password

Very new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

OK_Sooner

Comment: Just to clarify... You wish to connect from MySQL Workbench on your own computer to an Amazon RDS MySQL instance -- is that correct? If so, you do not SSH to RDS. Rather, you connect MySQL Workbench to port 3306 on the RDS instance using the Username & Password defined when the database was created. Similarly, no PEM files are required, since that's only for SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that security group of your instance accept connections from your ip. And as John Rotenstein said - you don't need to connect by ssh. Just connect to port 3306.

Comment: Followed your instructions, don't know what I did differently this time but it finally worked! Thanks so much!